# 3D geometry about a surface

Tags: geometry, area, 3d

I found this 3D geometry problem but i can't solve it !

"I have $20$ cubes of side $1$, which i assemble to form a large cube of side $3$ but without the cubes on the center of each face and without the cube in the center. Then, i place this solid on one of its vertex, so that two vertices diametrically opposite ends up vertical to each other, and then cut it in two by a horizontal plane located halfway between these two vertices. What is the area of the horizontal face common to the two halves?"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can see below how that surface looks like. It's formed by the [well-known regular hexagon](http://www.matematicasvisuales.com/english/html/geometry/space/hexagonalhalfcube.html) whose vertices are the midpoints of six edges of the cube, from which a central star-like hole has been cut out.

That happens because the central cubic hole is cut by the plane in the same way as the large cube, thus creating a hexagonal hole whose sides are one third of the sides of the large hexagon. On the other hand the plane doesn't pass through the center of the six lateral holes and just cuts them at six triangles, whose vertices are the midpoints of three concurring sides of the small cubes.

The large hexagon has sides of length ${3\over2}\sqrt2$, while the sides of the star are one third of those: ${1\over2}\sqrt2$. From that the area of the surface can be computed as ${21\over4}\sqrt3$.

[image]

Here's a detail of the central small cube with the other six cubic cavities attached to it, and the cutting plane.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i perfectly understood calculations. However i don't really understood how you managed to find the shape of this surface ? Could you explain again why is there a star shape, or where does this hexagon comes from ? Thank you for your patience because im starting in 3D geometry :D

Comment: http://www.matematicasvisuales.com/english/html/geometry/space/hexagonalhalfcube.html

Comment: You may check that hexagon is perpendicular to one of the diagonals of the cube, and intersects it at its midpoint.

Comment: I was looking at your proof @Intelligenti pauca. I do not see clearly where does the "star" shape comes from or how to prove it. Could you help me again please ? Thank you so much !

Comment: @mattandmaths I think the second figure is clear. The central cubelet is cut by the plane along a hexagon. Now produce the sides of this hexagon to meet (at their midpoint) the edges of the six neighbouring cubelets, thus creating the star shape.

Comment: I think i got it thank you

Comment: @Intelligentipauca i do not understand how to prove that the shape is a star or how to calculate its lenght ?

Comment: @maximegamelin To begin with, if the $3\times3\times3$ cube had no holes, then its intersection with the plane would be the blue regular hexagon in the first figure, whose sides have a length of $3\sqrt2/2$. Is that clear?

Comment: Yes everything is clear i think i understand

Comment: @maximegamelin OK. But the plane also intersects the hole, formed by the seven cubelets in the second figure. Note that the central cubelet has the same center and diagonals as the large cube, hence its intersection with the plane is a hexagon, whose sides are $1/3$ of the sides of the large blue hexagon. Is this clear?